# Free layer 2 traffic generator for Windows like iperf

Tags: windows, open-source, networking, network-monitor, iperf

I'm looking for a free working tool to generate layer 2 Ethernet frames. It would be nice to have a tool like iperf or similar (iperf doesn't support link layer).

In this question, I can find a few tools for layer 2, but none of them seems to be working under windows (and free of course).

Update: Scapy doesn't work with Win 7 64-bit, so don't suggest it.

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Welcome aboard. I notice that you say that you are "looking for a free working tool", but use the [tag:open-source] tag. If you really just need free and don't need the source code, then the [tag:gratis] tag generally attracts more answers

Comment: I have used Scapy with Windows 7/64 & 10/64 - you do need to follow the Windows install instructions __very__ carefully.